# How to implicitly add another column in active records migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

As you know, rails will add an `id` column as primary key implicitly when creating a table using migration.
My question is, if I want to add another column implicitly, is it possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to look into custom generators, particularly overriding the existing templates:

[http://guides.rubyonrails.org...](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates)

Maybe this is the file you want to copy/paste into your project directory and then edit?

[http://github.com...](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb)

Comment: It's a way, but it's explicit, not implicit